# JPAM Configuration for Apache Drill

Tags: centos, apache-drill, pam, openjpa-maven-plugin

I'm trying to configure PLAIN authentification based on JPAM 1.1 and am going crazy since it doesnt work after x times checking my syntax and settings. When I start drill with cluster-id and zk-connect only, it works, but with both options of PLAIN authentification it fails. Since I started with pam4j and tried JPAM later on, I kept JPAM for this post. In general I don't have any preferences. I just want to get it done. I'm running Drill on CentOS in embedded mode.

I've done anything required due to the official documentation:

- I downloaded JPAM 1.1, uncompressed it and put *libjpam.so* into a specific folder (/opt/pamfile/)
- I've edited drill-env.sh with: 
  `export DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/opt/pamfile/"`
- I edited *drill-override.conf* with:

  `drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "local",
  impersonation: {
    enabled: true,
    max_chained_user_hops: 3
  },
  security: {
    auth.mechanisms: ["PLAIN"],
  },
  security.user.auth: {
    enabled: true,
    packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security",
    impl: "pam",
    pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]
    }
  }`

It throws the subsequent error:

`Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Problem in finding the native library of JPAM (Pluggable Authenticator Module API). Make sure to set Drillbit JVM option 'java.library.path' to point to the directory where the  native JPAM exists.:no jpam in java.library.path (state=,code=0)`

I've run that *.sh file by hand to make sure that the necessary path is exported since I don't know if Drill is expecting that. The path to libjpam should be know known. I've started Sqlline with sudo et cetera. No chance. Documentation doesn't help. I don't get it why it's so bad and imo incomplete. Sadly there is 0 explanation how to troubleshoot or configure basic user authentification in detail.

Or do I have to do something which is not told but expected? Are there any Prerequsites concerning PLAIN authentification which aren't mentioned by Apache Drill itself?

Answer (score 2):

Try change:

`export DRILLBIT_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/opt/pamfile/"`

to:

`export DRILL_JAVA_OPTS="$DRILL_JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/opt/pamfile/"`

It works for me.